# keyboard.on_press_key() перестает вызывать функцию после компиляции в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, exe, keyboardhook

keyboard.on_press_key('f7', TranslateAll, suppress=True) при нажатии на *F7* вызывает функцию `TranslateAll()`.

**Алгоритм работы `TranslateAll():`**

1. Библиотека `pyperclip` вытаскивает из буфера обмена текст
2. Библиотека `googletrans` переводит текст
3. `pyperclip` вставляет обратно в б/о переведенный текст

Все отлично работает, однако, после компиляции в .exe, после ~10 вызовов функции, `keyboard.on_press_key()` перестает реагировать на нажатия или же вызывать функцию. Причем это не сопровождается какими-либо сообщениями в консоли. Просто нажимаю *F7* и все - никаких ошибок.

**!!! Проблема появляется только при работе с переводчиком `googletrans`, если отбросить его и оставить только работу с буфером обмена, то проблема уйдет!**

Пробовал указывать код клавиши, вместо 'f7' - проблема осталась.

Я также пробовал заново назначать *F7* в `keyboard.hook_key()` при ошибке (оборачивал алгоритм в try-except), но это тоже ничего не дало.

**Код:** Здесь все работает как надо, но если скомпилировать (pyinstaller PythonCode.py), то можно увидеть описанную мной проблему.

```
from googletrans import Translator
import keyboard
import googletrans
import pyperclip
 
count = 0                         #счетчик срабатываний функции
 
def TranslateAll(event):
    global count
    #основной алгоритм 
    translator = Translator()
    data = pyperclip.paste()
    result = translator.translate(data, dest='ru')
    pyperclip.copy(result.text)

    count += 1
    print(f'Срабатывание №{count}\n')

    
#привязка F7 к функции
keyboard.on_press_key('f7', TranslateAll, suppress=True)
keyboard.wait()
```

**Готовый проблемный .exe-файл также можно скачать с моего гугл диска:** [PythonCode.exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJCI1-xohp8oC4SmZqWeTx4AkxyjcwB8/view?usp=sharing)

**Также имеется видео с подробным обзором на проблему:** [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INgx8XA1foM&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=DenisNumba)

Comment: Я так помню там какая-то хитрая хрень в винде банит это в экзешках. ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239618/codekeylogger-converted-into-exe-with-pyinstaller-not-working-as-it-was

Comment: а запускаете от админа ?

Comment: При запуске от админа тоже ничего не выходит. Убрать гугл переводчик - все будет работать. Даже если заменить строку с переводом на `result = f'{data} - текст пропущен через функцию'`, все будет прекрасно работать. Именно гуглтранс почему-то сбивает вызов функции после 6 нажатий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в строке вызова функции `keyboard.on_press_key('f7', TranslateAll, suppress=True)`

**Значение параметра `suppress` нужно было поменять с `True` на `False`.**

Comment: А зачем нужен был `suppress=True`? Посмотрел в библиотеке, там `suppress` и так уже имеет значение `False`, т.е. просто: `keyboard.on_press_key('f7', TranslateAll)`

Comment: Так вот именно, я и сам не понял зачем добавил параметр